# Android R8 Instant Crash

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, proguard, android-r8

I am trying to build a release version of my application with **R8 full mode** but it results to crashes. More specifically, when installing through Android Studio either the build will be fully functional or it will crash at once with the stacktraces added below.

Sometimes it happens immediately after configuration changes, e.g `debuggable false` to `debuggable true` and sometimes after consecutive builds of the same gradle configuration which is very weird and I can not determine its behavior.

```
release {
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    minifyEnabled true
    debuggable false
    shrinkResources true
}
```

Proguard file:

```
-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
       public *;
}

## kotlin
-dontwarn org.jetbrains.annotations.**
-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }

-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.**
-keep class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.* { *; }

-keepclassmembers class kotlin.Metadata {
   public <methods>;
}

-keepnames @dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel class * extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
```

The application is built with

- Android Studio 4.2.1
- AGP Version 4.2.1
- Gradle Version gradle-6.7.1-all

Due to Jetpack Compose inclusion we have also added:

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
            freeCompilerArgs += [
                    "-Xallow-jvm-ir-dependencies",
                    "-P",
                    "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck=true"
            ]
        }
}


compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

```
coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'
```

Moreover `multiDexEnabled true` and `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.5.10"` which would be a possible solution is included.

Crash 1:

```
E/zd3: SafeAtomicHelper is broken!
    java.lang.ClassCastException
        at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater$AtomicReferenceFieldUpdaterImpl.<init>(AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.java:352)
        at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.newUpdater(AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.java:109)
        at zd3.<clinit>(Unknown Source:96)
        at be3.t(Unknown Source:46)
        at d93.<init>(Unknown Source:41)
        at ad3.<init>(Unknown Source:77)
        at i93.a(Unknown Source:186)
        at r93.c(Unknown Source:410)
        at qg8.<init>(Unknown Source:247)
        at og8.b(Unknown Source:108)
        at MyAppApplication.c(Unknown Source:74)
        at MyAppApplication.onCreate(Unknown Source:44)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1190)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleMakeApplication(ActivityThread.java:7184)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7134)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:274)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2102)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Crash 2:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
       at kotlin.LazyKt__LazyJVMKt.lazy(LazyKt__LazyJVMKt.java:34)
       at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KProperty1Impl.<init>(KProperty1Impl.java:41)
       at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectionFactoryImpl.property1(ReflectionFactoryImpl.java:18)
       at kotlin.jvm.internal.Reflection.property1(Reflection.java:2)
       at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KDeclarationContainerImpl$Data.<clinit>(KDeclarationContainerImpl.java:18)
       at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$data$1.invoke(KClassImpl.java)
       at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$data$1.invoke(KClassImpl.java)
       at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazyVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:11)
       at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getSimpleName(KClassImpl.java:2)
       at com.android.tools.r8.GeneratedOutlineSupport.outline55(GeneratedOutlineSupport.java:4)
       at MyAppViewModel.subscribe(MyAppViewModel.java:2)
       at MyAppActivity.onResume(MyAppActivity.java:26)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1454)
       at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:8111)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4647)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4690)
       at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2267)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException
       at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater$AtomicReferenceFieldUpdaterImpl.<init>(AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.java:352)
       at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.newUpdater(AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.java:109)
       at kotlin.SafePublicationLazyImpl.<clinit>(SafePublicationLazyImpl.java:6)
       at kotlin.LazyKt__LazyJVMKt.lazy(LazyKt__LazyJVMKt.java:34)
       at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KProperty1Impl.<init>(KProperty1Impl.java:41)
       at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectionFactoryImpl.property1(ReflectionFactoryImpl.java:18)
       at kotlin.jvm.internal.Reflection.property1(Reflection.java:2)
       at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KDeclarationContainerImpl$Data.<clinit>(KDeclarationContainerImpl.java:18)
       at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$data$1.invoke(KClassImpl.java)
       at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$data$1.invoke(KClassImpl.java)
       at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazyVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:11)
       at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getSimpleName(KClassImpl.java:2)
       at com.android.tools.r8.GeneratedOutlineSupport.outline55(GeneratedOutlineSupport.java:4)
       at MyAppViewModel.subscribe(MyAppViewModel.java:2)
       at MyAppActivity.onResume(MyAppActivity.java:26)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1454)
       at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:8111)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4647)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4690)
       at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2267)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Comment: I have turned this into an R8 issue, https://issuetracker.google.com/190382641. Please CC yourself on that follow up there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question. A workaround is to add the following rule in your proguard-rules.pro:

```
-keepclassmembers class kotlin.SafePublicationLazyImpl {
    java.lang.Object _value;
}
```

Issue is tracked at [Google's issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/190382641)